# Implementation of a function to check who wins on a TicTacToe game

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, game-engine, simplify

This is my first approach to programming and I'm trying to create a TicTacToe game.At the moment, I'm doing a function that checks if a winning play is happening, but I'm sure that there are better ways to do this that my actual code. Any suggestions?
This is what I have:

```
let boardGame = new Array(9)
let turn = 'x';
let winner;
let squares = document.getElementsByClassName('board') // this variable it is used in other functions that I'm not transcribing it.

let whoWins = (boardGame) =>{

    if(boardGame[0] == 'x' && boardGame[1] == 'x' && boardGame[2]== 'x' || boardGame[3] == 'x' && boardGame[4] == 'x' && boardGame[5]== 'x' || boardGame[6] == 'x' && boardGame[7] == 'x' && boardGame[8]== 'x' || boardGame[0] == 'x' && boardGame[4] == 'x' && boardGame[8]== 'x' || boardGame[2] == 'x' && boardGame[4] == 'x' && boardGame[6]== 'x' || boardGame[0] == 'x' && boardGame[3] == 'x' && boardGame[6]== 'x' || boardGame[1] == 'x' && boardGame[4] == 'x' && boardGame[7]== 'x' || boardGame[2] == 'x' && boardGame[5] == 'x' && boardGame[8]== 'x'){
        
       winner = 'x'
      

}
    else if(boardGame[0] == 'o' && boardGame[1] == 'o' && boardGame[2]== 'o' || boardGame[3] == 'o' && boardGame[4] == 'o' && boardGame[5]== 'o' || boardGame[6] == 'o' && boardGame[7] == 'o' && boardGame[8]== 'o' || boardGame[0] == 'o' && boardGame[4] == 'o' && boardGame[8]== 'o' || boardGame[2] == 'o' && boardGame[4] == 'o' && boardGame[6]== 'o' || boardGame[0] == 'o' && boardGame[3] == 'o' && boardGame[6]== 'o' || boardGame[1] == 'o' && boardGame[4] == 'o' && boardGame[7]== 'o' || boardGame[2] == 'o' && boardGame[5] == 'o' && boardGame[8]== 'o'){
            winner = 'o'
    }
else{}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this function hoping it's not too difficult to approach with.
In case I can simplify it just let me know:)

```
let whoWins = (boardGame) => {

  const winningConditions = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8]
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];

  const winner = winningConditions.find(
    (condition) =>
      boardGame[condition[0]] === boardGame[condition[1]] &&
      boardGame[condition[1]] === boardGame[condition[2]]
  );
  
  // if the game is not finished exit
  if (winner === undefined) return;
  
  
  winner = boardGame[winner[0]];
};
```

Grazie

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution, it was really helpful to me as a guide.
I made some changes, using your code as a source, and I came up with this code:

Comment: Happy to know that Daiana, btw I can't see the code :'). Please consider accepting my function as the solution to your problem since it helps you! thanks